# Can you DIY replacing shower door hardware?

Tags: bathroom, doors, shower, bathroom-fixtures

Chrome hardware was mistakenly installed on our shower door. The contractor's quote is too high for  a replacement to black. Is it possible to DIY? What materials would be needed to change the hardware?[image]

Comment: This really depends on the capabilities of the DIYer doing the work.  Based on your question, perhaps you may want to rethink the "expensive" quote as a new door is likely going to be a lot more than that.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the exact same handle as shown in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sZ8E4gGmAAQ

Seems like you just need the new hardware, a phillips head screwdriver, and an allen wrench (hex key).

Additional video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XR9HvO9eAdI

Answer (score 1):

If the exact model of door is available with black hinges and handle, and if you can order those replacement parts, the question of whether you can do the work yourself can be answered by yourself by reading the installation instructions and determining whether you have the skills and confidence.  This is not a job for developing new skills.  If you're not comfortable with a screwdriver, or with any aspect of the installation, you don't want to be learning about it while working with a big heavy piece of glass that has to be precisely aligned.  On the other hand, you don't need to drill into tile because that's already done so you may only need basic skills.

If you can't easily order the correct black parts, forget it.  It doesn't look so bad.  If you try to hack it, it will look terrible.

Comment: +1 -- these doors are heavy, and one wrong click on something hard can reduce them to small cubes. At a minimum, you need two strong people and proper (not the 20 dollar crapola) suction cups -- think Wood's brand and ~80 bucks each). If I was desperate, I'd change the handle (easy!) and paint the hinges.

Comment: Plus, torquing the grub screws on the hinges is petrifying. Not tight enough and the door sags. Too tight, and it shatters.

Comment: We have technology to deal with "too little torque bad / too much torque bad". @aloy